# How to download youtube-8m dataset using curl

Tags: windows, curl, download, windows-10, command-prompt

The Youtube-8m download webpage provides the following curl instructions:

```
mkdir -p ~/data/yt8m_video_level; cd ~/data/yt8m_video_level 

curl data.yt8m.org/download.py | partition=1/video_level/train mirror=us python 
curl data.yt8m.org/download.py | partition=1/video_level/validate mirror=us python 
curl data.yt8m.org/download.py | partition=1/video_level/test mirror=us python
```

I have made the directory and am now trying to download the training data.

When I execute:

```
curl data.yt8m.org/download.py | partition=1/video_level/train mirror=us python
```

I receive the following error message:

> 'partition' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

If I use a caret to escape the | like so:

```
curl data.yt8m.org/download.py ^| partition=1/video_level/train mirror=us python
```

Then the command prompt prints the entire contents of http://data.yt8m.org/download.py followed by:

> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: |
>   curl: (6) Could not resolve host: partition=1
>   curl: (6) Could not resolve host: mirror=eu
>   curl: (6) Could not resolve host: python

How do I use curl to download this dataset to Windows 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That script is intended to run in a `*nix` (`Unix` or `linux` or ...) environment.

Do you have the `bash` for windows installed? If so, that is the quick solution, just run the script/cmds in that environment (and make sure that `which python` returns the correct `/path/to/preferred/version_of/python`).

To explain/expand on what that code does, `*nix` allows setting env vars specific to the command being run at the end of the line. An alternate way to "say" the same thing as the code you have included in `*nix` is

```
export partition=1/video_level/test
export mirror=us 
curl data.yt8m.org/download.py | python
```

So you *want* the `|` as a pipe, and don't want to escape it.

The equivalent in old DOS `.bat` file would be

```
set partition = 1/video_level/test
set mirror = us 
curl data.yt8m.org/download.py | python
```

But, older versions of `dos` used to have a limit of how much could be "stored" in a `|` (pipe). I don't know what the current limits in the Windows Cmd-Prompt are, so you may need to create your own temp files and then feed them in, i.e.

```
set partition = 1/video_level/test
set mirror = us 
curl data.yt8m.org/download.py > %TEMP%\mytempFile
python < %TEMP%\mytempFile
```

I'm not a `python` programmer, so I may be missing something completely obvious to pythonistas.

---

Just looked at the source code to download.py. Did you notice this

```
print ('Starting fresh download in this directory. Please make sure you '
    'have >2TB of free disk space!')
```

IHTH

Comment: In response to the 2TB warning, the associated web page says that you need 1.71TB if you are installing the frame_level dataset and 31GB if you are installing the video_level dataset. I cannot say that I understand the source code to see the different streams for downloading a specific dataset but it seems from the webpage that I should be ok. Thank you for the extra effort to check the source code!